# Visual Studio Code "Combine icon packs"

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to use two icon packs  at the same time.

One for file and another for folders.

How do I do that?

Comment: what happens if you install them both

Comment: You could make your own theme.. and take what icons you want from the one theme and put it to the other and that way you have exactly what you want

Comment: @Costa Thank You Very Much for helping me out maybe you should post this as an answer not a comment, So that I can mark as the best answer. Anyway, Thank You Very Much

Comment: @rioV8 Thank you for commenting. When I install multiple icon packs Visual Studio Code only let's me to select one. But Thank You for suggesting a way.